# iOS 6 Developer Preview 4 vs official iOS update

Tags: ios6

I have had iOS DP4 installed since it was released on my iPhone. Now that the official update is released, I go in to Settings to check for updates but it says my OS is up to date. Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download iOS6: http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/19/ios-6-ipsw-direct-download-links/

Upgrade iTunes to at least 10.7

Connect your iPhone to iTunes

(backup your device)

Shift+click the update button, specify the update file manually (the one that you downloaded in step 1)

Click Go.